How do you ensure that calendar invites won't be moved out of your inbox when your rules are executed?
While I haven't had it happen yet, I worry about having a Calendar Invite sent to some other folder based on rules I've setup for emails. Is this something I don't have to worry about, or is there some way to make sure it doesn't happen?

Do you have a concern about specific criteria that may impact calendar invites sent to you?

@music2myear, Yes, it's possible a calendar invite might have text that a rule catches and files it away.

In the Manual Rules wizard in Outlook 365 there is an Exceptions panel, and among the exceptions is one titled "except if it is a meeting invitation or update".
Taking this at face value, I believe it tells us that yes, inbox rules WILL run against calendar invites that meet the criteria you specify, and that you can use this exception to prevent that happening.
